# Setting up a redox reaction using chemmacros

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros

I've been trying to set up this redox reaction for quite some time now, having searched the web for answers and being unable to find them I resorted to ask in here. I'm looking for a way to modify the code below so that hydrazine molecule can stay as a molecule but get the right amount of atoms, currently I'm only able to append a number to the last atom in the molecule, but not on the nitrogen atom, does anyone have a solution or workaround for this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,danish,11pt,final]{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}

\vspace{7mm}
\ch{
"\OX{o1,\ox{0,N}\ox{0,Cl}}" {}2 + "\OX{r1,\ox{0,Cl}}" {}3
->
"\OX{o2,\ox{+1,Na}}" {}+ + 2 "\OX{r2,\ox{-1,Cl}}" {}-
}
\redox(o1,o2){\small OX: $- 2\el$}
\redox(r1,r2)[][-1]{\small RED: $+ 2\el$}
\vspace{7mm}

\end{document}
```

Ends up looking like this:
[image: pic]

I wanna append the 2 to the Nitrogen instead of the Chlorine atom. We're looking at the first molecule here, I wanted to get that one setup before writing the rest out, seeing how the first one didn't go too well..

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Which »code below«?

Comment: Added in! Sorry about that, prematurely pressed enter or something and it posted.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Not ideal but: `"\OX{o1,\ox{1,N}\chcpd{2}\ox{-1,Cl}}" {}2`. Possibly `"\OX{o1,\ox{1,N}\chcpd{2}\ox{-1,Cl}\chcpd{2}}"`

Comment: Pouya: I see what you're saying, will keep that in mind!

clemens: Might not be too ideal, but it works, and that's all I really care about right now ;) Now how do I mark something as an answer on here, if that's possible?

Comment: @Shisk In terms of stoichiometry, the equation as shown by today - March 4th, 2023 - is not balanced, hence wrong.  Can you correct it, please? (Just by reference to [chemistry.se](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/171876/can-you-write-oxidation-states-with-negative-roman-numerals).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\chcpd` inside `\OX`, `\ox` (and even `\ch`) for typesetting compounds. `\chcpd` is described in the manual for `chemformula`. In this case you can use it for adding the subscripts. It looks a bit clumsy but works…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}

\ch{
"\OX{o1,\ox{1,N}\chcpd{2}\ox{-1,Cl}\chcpd{2}}" + "\OX{r1,\ox{0,Cl}}" {}3
->
"\OX{o2,\ox{+1,Na}}" {}+ + 2 "\OX{r2,\ox{-1,Cl}}" {}-
}
\redox(o1,o2){\small OX: $- 2\el$}
\redox(r1,r2)[][-1]{\small RED: $+ 2\el$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From the perspective of chemistry, the above reaction equation is *awfully wrong*.  Not balanced in atoms (5 chlorine atoms left, 2 on the right), and suggesting transformation of nitrogen N to sodium Na.  But so equally is the one in the original question, too.  Just spot because of a relevant question on [chemistry.se](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/171876/can-you-write-oxidation-states-with-negative-roman-numerals/171880#171880).

Comment: @Buttonwood true ;)

Comment: Do you want to advance to correct $\ce{N2Cl2}$ and $\ce{Cl3}$ to something to the result of $\ce{2 Na + Cl2 -> 2 Na+  + 2 Cl^-}$?  Second surprise: chemistry.se has [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) up and running in the bodies of questions, answers, and comments while tex.se does not.  So far, I assumed mhchem would be a tool all across stackexchange, including tex.se (or at least here; if not mistaken, `mhchem` once started as usepackage for LaTeX, *subsequently* entered MathJax & Cie.